# Simple question on A/B testing

Tags: probability, chi-squared-test, pooling

Hi there I have a question that I am confused as how to answer. So I have a balanced dataset of 500 observations split between 2 groups. 250 are a control group and 250 are an experimental group. The response variable is wether or not they are cured from a disease (0 or 1) in the control group there are 29 who are cured and in the experimental group there were 42 who were cured.

The question asks me to then calculated a pooled standard error and a pooled probability. This confuses me as my immediate guess was to use a chi-squared or fisher exact test to then hypothesis test the data.

So how would I calculate the 'pooled probability' and pooled standard error for this data? I have actually never heard of the term pooled probability before to be honest.

I have drawn the probability grid below[image]

Thank you for reading and feel free to ask for clarification if I didn't explain the question well enough

P.S I wasn't sure if this was supposed to be asked here or on mathexchange I asked it here because it was stats related.

Comment: This is called a "contingency table."  The term "probability grid" sounds inappropriate because it doesn't display any probabilities.  Knowing the name helps when searching for what ["pooled probability"](https://www.google.com/search?q=contingency+table+pooled+estimate) might mean.

Comment: Ah I see thank you for telling me what this is called we used to just call them "punnet squares" at school but searching for that sounded strange!

Comment: A "punnet square" is a specialized version of a $2\times 2$ table used in genomics. It does not appear to be used to analyze count data.  "Contingency table" covers tables of count data having arbitrary numbers of rows and columns and even extends to tables with more than three dimensions.